# PHP password_verify() doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql

I have been going through the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` methods in PHP and I've been trying to include that in my code. I can't seem to get it to work, I've gone through series of googling and even some of the questions here on SO but they don't seem to resolve the issue.

My column length in the database is 255. When I try to run the code, I get the `$loginerror` message. Here's my code block. Please what am I doing wrong.

```
$signin_email=$_POST['signin_email'];
$signin_password=$_POST['signin_password'];

if($valid){
    require_once 'scripts/connect_to_mysql.php';
    $sql = "SELECT First_name, Last_name,Password FROM customer WHERE Email=? AND Password=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);//preparing the statement
    if(!$stmt){
        echo "Unable to prepare: ".$conn->errno. " " .$conn->error;
    }
    //executing the statement
    //$date=date('d m Y h:i:s');
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('ss', $signin_email, $signin_password)){//bind parameters to sql statement. i=integer, s=string, b=blob, d=double 
        echo "Binding parameters failed: ".$stmt->errno. " " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()){//executing the statement
        echo "Statement Execution failed: ". $stmt->error;
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_result($dbfirstname,$dblastname,$dbpassword)){// used to bind variables to a prepared statement for result storage
        echo "Unable to bind results to variables: ".$stmt->error;
    }
    $stmt->store_result();
    //echo $stmt->num_rows;
    echo $dbpassword;
    if(password_verify($signin_password, $dbpassword)){
        if($stmt->num_rows===1){//to check if username and password actually exists
            while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
                $user=$dbfirstname. " ". $dblastname;
                echo $user;
            }

            /*$_SESSION['user']=$user;
            header('location:logintest.php');
            exit();*/
        }
    }
    else{
        //$error="Invalid Email address/Password. Please try again";
        $loginerror= "Invalid Email address/Password. Please try again";
    }

    $stmt->close();//closing the prepared statement
    $conn->close();//closing the connection
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem does not lie in `password_verify` but in way that you build your query:

```
`$sql ="SELECT First_name, Last_name,Password FROM customer WHERE Email=? AND Password=? LIMIT 1";
```

You bind `$signin_password` to that query and it contains not hashed value from `$_POST`.

There are 2 solutions:

1) remove `AND Password=?` from your query - you will check your password with `password_verify`

2) change `$signin_password` to:

```
$signin_password=password_hash($_POST['signin_password']);
```

(but  this way using password_verify is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Note that the second option should be strongly discouraged, since `password_hash` is designed to transparently upgrade to a stronger hash algorithm in future. `password_verify` looks at the hash that was used when the record was created, which may not be the current default.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MarkS. hashing `$signin_password` will make it not equal to the password in the database as it creates a new hash different from the one created before. I removed the `AND Password=?`from my query, still got the same result. Please help.

Comment: well, if hashed `$signin_password` is not equal to he value in db then your password in db is just different or hashed with different algorithm.

Comment: Yes, thinking about it, even without a change in algorithm, re-running `password_hash` will generate a new "salt" (so that two users with the same password don't get the same hash), meaning that removing `and password=` from your WHERE clause is the only right answer.

Comment: That exactly what happens @IMSoP, each time I try to echo the hash for the same password i get different values. So hashing the password again doesn't solve the problem, removing `and password=`doesn't either. I'm going crazy here, please help.

Comment: @IMSoP Are you there?

Answer (score -1):

```
$signin_password=$_POST['signin_password'];

$hash = password_hash($dbpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($signin_password, $hash)) 

 {

   echo 'Password is valid!';

 } 

 else 

 {

   echo 'Invalid password.';

 }
```

Try with this :) Better option is just build your own query.

Comment: Hashing the `$dbpassword` would make no sense: the whole point of hashing is that all that is stored in the DB is the *result* of the hash.